# Parsing data from a table on a website with zero entries entered as "-"

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[Screenshot of Toronto Raptors Stats from nba.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gytwM.png)
I am trying to parse data from a table found on nba.com but the problem is that the zero entries are not entered as "0", but instead are entered as "-".

If the entry is not zero, it is contained in a td tag with a certain class (ex. class="pts"25 for points).  If the entry is zero, the td tag has no class, instead it is simply -.

I am using the beautiful soup library to parse this data and I tried finding all the td tags and using an if statement in order to append "0" to my array instead of the "-" character (see code).  When I go to print out the player name, number, games played, and points in a CSV format the points are not printed next to the correct player.

```
points = soup.find_all("td")

for point in points:

    if point.has_attr("class") and point["class"][0]=="pts":
        points_array.append(point.text)
    elif point.text=="—":
        points_array.append("0")
    else:
        pass
```

I expect that the program should skip over any td tags that do not have a class="pts" or a text attribute equal to "-".  After the "for point in points" for loop the points_array should have the same number of elements as the other three arrays (names_array, numbers_array, games_array) and all the player's stats should be at the same index in the respective array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use zip to join lists, replace to replace the text and adjacent sibling combinator to ensure list length for points is the same as the others as you will always take the adjacent column value irrespective of class/no class.

```
import csv, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.nba.com/raptors/stats')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

with open("nba.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline='') as csv_file:
    w = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    w.writerow(['Name','Number','Games Played','Points'])

    for name, number, games, points in zip(soup.select('.playerName a'), soup.select('.playerNumber'), soup.select('td.gp'), soup.select('td.gp + td')):
        w.writerow([name.text, number.text, games.text, points.text.replace('—','0')])
```